# What medal is shown in this 19th-century Canadian picture?

Tags: 19th-century, identification, british-empire

I have a photo of a Canadian male ancestor from around 1885 (he is about 45 years old), who is wearing a medal (see photo).  I am having trouble identifying what the medal is. The photo quality is not good enough to identify what is imprinted on the 16-point star, but the ribbon bar has the letters C-H-A and there is a symbol of a key and something else on the ribbon. Does anyone recognize this?

Comment: Including the photo would help...

Comment: "CHA" might be the [Canadian Heraldic Authority](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canadian_Heraldic_Authority), some of whose officers' badges also contain a 16-pointed star... +1 let's see that photo.

Comment: trying to repost the photo again. having difficulty due to file size

Comment: I keep getting a server error when I try to attach photo. Any suggestions?

Comment: initial attempt was jpeg filesize 252kb. I rescanned the image on lower resolution, pic is now 26kb, which should be below the system limit.

Comment: @RickS still no photo visible.